# Редирект mail iptables

Tags: iptables, email, спам

С сервера идет исходящий спам, причем не через спам скрипты (которые можно было бы обнаружить через X-php-script патч), а предположительно через исходящие коннекты на открытые релеи. Как такое можно засечь?

Есть мысль перевести все OUTPUT запросы 25 порт на второй сервер и там уже логировать. Каким образом наиболее корректно провести подобную операцию?

Answer (score 1):

А почему вы не хотите использовать логирование на этом же сервере, -j LOG или -j ULOG?Если же вы хотите более интеллектуальные методы, воспользуйтесь [Snort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snort_(software)), для детектирования.

Очень много зависит от того, сколько ресурсов вы готовы на это пожертвовать, какова частота и критичность данного спама и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

> предположительно через исходящие коннекты на открытые релеи

Это как? Спамить можно через phpmail или sendmail, postfix , telnet, etc...

> Каким образом наиболее корректно провести подобную операцию?

- фильтровать кол-во конектов
- снифить tcpdump например

Answer (score 1):

ну или если живёт какой-либо сервис и спамит посмотреть его так

sockstat | grep ":25"